# Bitbucket - how to update the build logs & artifacts without Jenkins/Bamboo?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm using Bitbucket Server and I'm trying to figure out how to update the "rich build status"--the Logs and Artifacts for builds in Bitbucket. Currently, the Bitbucket documentation only references [Jenkins and Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/link-your-ci-server-1032257995.html#LinkyourCIserver-Integrationguides), but we're trying to accomplish this simply via REST API instead of using a CI server.

[Bitbucket does say](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/link-your-ci-server-1032257995.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20use%20a%20different%20CI%20server%2C%20you%20can%20integrate%20with%C2%A0Bitbucket%20and%20send%20it%20detailed%20builds%20information%20using%20our%20REST%20API.%20For%20more%20on%20how%20to%20do%20this%2C%20see%20our%20REST%20resources.), however:

> If you use a different CI server, you can integrate with Bitbucket and send it detailed builds information using our REST API. For more on how to do this, see our REST resources.

Looking at the [REST documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v805/api-group-builds-and-deployments/#api-group-builds-and-deployments) they link, I don't see anything talking about how to update the Logs/Artifacts for a build.

So is this possible outside of an established CI server? If so, where how would I do it or how would I find the process?

Comment: It's currently not possible. There is an open feature request for this functionality - [BSERV-12946](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-12946)